# Proof involving a $4\times 4$ irreducible non-negative matrix and its eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_4(\Bbb R)$ be an irreducible matrix and let $h=2$ be the period of $A$. Prove that, if $A$ has no pure imaginary eigenvalue, then all its eigenvalues are real.

By [period of $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Classification_of_matrices) I mean the $MCD$ of all the lenghts of paths in the graph $\Gamma(A)$. Correct me if the English word for this entity is different.

*My attempt*:

$A$ is irreducible and not primitive, thus for the [Fröbenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_matrices) its spectral radius $r = r(A)\in \Bbb R$ and two of its $4$ eigenvalues are $r, -r$, since $h=2$.

Now the other two must be complex (or real) and such that $Tr(A)=0$; in fact $h=2$ and we now that $a_{ii}^{(k)} = 0$ for $k\notin h\Bbb N$, where $a_{ij}^{(k)}$ denotes the generical element of $A^k$; so the diagonal of $A$ is $0$ and since the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues (invariant for similitude), **the two should be opposites**.

Thus, since the last two eigenvalue are solutions of a $2^{nd}$-order equation, they **should be conjugate** one of each other and opposites, and since **they cannot be pure imaginary** they should be real.

Is it correct or am I missing something (about complex numbers I guess) ?

Comment: Your proof looks good to me.